# Excel Vba runtime error?

Tags: vba, excel

When I tried to execute the below code, I got the error message as "Run-time error '424' Object Required",

```
Sub test()
Range("Q" & i).Text = x1.Text
End Sub
```

Where x1 is calender object.

If I would use the below code as

```
Range("Q" & i) = x1.Text
```

My code would store the date as 02-11-2013 instead of 11-02-2013, the problem here is it re-arranges it month and date.

Hope I will have the solution for this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'd guess on your first error, you are using x1 in a scope it is not defined.  Unless x1 is a global (probably not), you need to pass a reference to it in the sub's declaration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting an error in the first instance since the `.Text` property of a range is read-only and is used to get the current formatted value *from* a cell/range.

I'd use the format function but also set the number format of the cell you're putting it into to be safe:

```
Range("Q" & i).Value = Format(x1.Text, "dd-mm-yyyy")
Range("Q" & i).NumberFormat = "dd-mm-yyyy;@"
```

Edit:
Further to you comment, I'd suggest trying to Format the incoming date with the day and month swapped and then applying the NumberFormat like so:

```
Range("Q" & i).Value = Format(x1.Text, "mm-dd-yyyy")
Range("Q" & i).NumberFormat = "dd-mm-yyyy;@"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Format function:

```
    Range("Q" & i).Value = Format(x1.Text, "dd-mm-yyyy")
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly Use `Range("Q" & i) = Format(x1.Text,"dd-MM-yyyy")`